# How can I start to use tippero on #monero Freenode IRC?

Tags: tippero, irc

I need to have my nickname registered with Freenode for some of the #monero IRC features, including tippero. How can I register my nickname?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, while it's a legitimate question, it really belongs to some other SE site related to IRC

Comment: @JollyMort I agree that IRC in general is off topic, but do you think this may be an exception since tippero is Monero specific?

Comment: It came up in review; If nobody else votes to close it will remain open :) I suppose if the question was framed as "How can I use all tippero features?" or something, we could sqeeze it in

Answer (score 4):

There are some instructions on this web page: https://freenode.net/kb/answer/registration

Basically, you enter the command:

`/msg NickServ REGISTER yourpassword youremail@example.com`

Then you will receive an email containing a command you will have to run to complete the registration.

After that, to connect to Freenode with your nickname, you can either use SASL (https://freenode.net/kb/answer/sasl) or connect with the command:

`/connect chat.freenode.net 6667 yournickname:yourpassword`

Comment: Can you please paste some of the highlights here, in case the webpage changes or is moved to a different URL?